# How to form single string from argument array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a reason argument properly for my moderation commands.
I plan to have it be executed like this:

```
!warn <@UserMention> [reason]
```

I have it set up so any word that comes after the command name would be sliced into an array of arguments.

```
let messageArray = message.content.split(/\s+/g);
let cmd = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);
let command = cmd.slice(prefix.length);
```

I could just have moderators put the reasons between quotes so the console reads it as one string, but that creates a slight inconvenience. How would I splice any amount of arguments starting at `args[1]` to make a full string labeled "reason"?

Comment: This isn't working? Looks fine to me.

Comment: You see, I want to be able to do something like...
"!warn @DomTrues this is a test reason"
I need to know how to splice every argument used starting at args[1] to be able to create a "reason" string. (args[1] being the word "this" in the example)

Comment: I understand your goal; isn't your code doing just that? Are you asking how to join it into one message, or?

Comment: All it does is slice the message into a command variable (ex. "!help") and the arguments (args)

Comment: I want to do something like "let reason = args[1] + " " + args[2] + " "...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all you're having trouble with is getting a single message instead an array of arguments.

You can just `Array#join` the arguments:

```
let msg = messageArray.slice(1).join(' ');
```

This will join all the words of the message with a single space. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use array.Reduce

`someArray = ["I","like","icecream"]
 someArray.reduce((total, value) => total + value, "")
 //becomes "Ilikeicecream"`

Feel free to add spaces at the end of each word.